# How to fall through a Select Case in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, office-2007

Given

```
Select Case cmd

    case "ONE":   MsgBox "one"

    case "TWO":   MsgBox "two"

    case "THREE": MsgBox "three"

End select
```

My requirement is if `cmd = "ONE"` I need  `"one"` and then `"two"` displayed however currently I am getting `"one"` displayed and then the program is breaking out of the select case...

Comment: I _think_ that's by design; the code automatically jumps to the end after the last statement in the case. You'll have to program around it (by using procedures, for example) instead.

Comment: @Gratzy: if cmd = "two" it should default to printing "two" and break out... I guess this is the default behavior in VBA.. I think VBA implicitly adds "break" statements after each case, which I want to bypass.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Select Case cmd
    case "ONE", "TWO":   
                  if cmd = "ONE" THEN
                      MsgBox "one"
                  end if
                  MsgBox "two"

    case "THREE": MsgBox "three"

End select
```

Comment: i'm trying to help sir, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Some if could do the job:

```
If cmd = "ONE" Then 
    MsgBox "one"
    cmd = "TWO"
End If
If cmd = "TWO" Then 
    MsgBox "two"
    cmd = "THREE"
End If
If Cmd = "THREE" Then 
    MsgBox "three"
End If
```

Comment: Nice workaround! I would recommended this as the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I've found the most readable and scale-able solution to be a small state-machine.

Simply wrap the `Select` in a `While` and end each case with which case is next.

```
While cmd <> ""
Select Case cmd
    Case "ONE"
        MsgBox  "one"
        cmd = "TWO"
    Case "TWO"
        MsgBox  "two"
        cmd = ""
    Case "THREE"
        MsgBox  "three"
        cmd = ""
End Select
Wend
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll just have to do it the long way.

```
Select Case cmd

    case "ONE":   MsgBox "one"
                  MsgBox "two"
                  MsgBox "three"

    case "TWO":   MsgBox "two"
                  MsgBox "three"

    case "THREE": MsgBox "three"

End select
```

Answer (score 1):

That is by design. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177199%28PROT.10%29.aspx

You could try using 'goto' or procedure calls to get around it.

Comment: Fine! can I do something like enter case "ONE": do some processing and then say GOTO case "TWO" or add some label under the case "TWO" statement.

Comment: Yes, but it'd be really ugly and very hard to debug (and anyone inheriting the code will not be pleased having to weed through "spaghetti code").

Answer (score 1):

GoTo would work well, I think.

```
Select Case cmd

    Case "ONE"
        MsgBox "one"
        GoTo AfterONE:

    Case "TWO"
AfterONE:
        MsgBox "two"

    Case "THREE"
        MsgBox "three"

End Select
```

It works; I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Select Case for this? All you're doing is printing the lower-case version of whatever value 'cmd' is.

```
If cmd = "ONE" Then
  MsgBox LCase$(cmd)
  MsgBox "two"
Else
  Msgbox LCase$(cmd)
End If
```

Comment: Actually I have shown lower case just for a descriptive purposes, practically there will be code written in those cases..and the condition that I want is if the program enters through cmd = "ONE" it should execute some code in "ONE" and then fall thru' to "TWO"...

Answer (score 0):

'Fall through' in a non-empty Case is a big source of errors in C/C++, so not implemented in most other languages (including VBA). So, as stated elsewhere, do it the long way and consider procedure calls to avoid duplication.

However, if like me you ended up on this page because you couldn't remember how to do **empty** drop-through, then a slight variation on the accepted answer is that you can (as with all VBA's commands) use an underscore to denote continuation onto the next line:

```
Select Case cmd
Case "ONE", _
     "TWO":   
    if cmd = "ONE" Then MsgBox "one"
    MsgBox "two"
Case "THREE":
    MsgBox "three"
End select
```